# Posse nominations for Aaronut

Tags: discussion, posse

So I caught wind of this ["Summer Cleaning"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/programmers-se-summer-cleaning/) project y'all are running. Sounds like a real good time, especially if there are s'mores and plenty of references to unicorns in the Augean Stables...

But good ol' [Aaron, he's latched onto the idea](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/programmers-se-summer-cleaning/1855#1855) of targeting [programming-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) for some *hard-core exorcism*. Armed with bell, book, candle, and close votes, he's ventured alone into this wasteland...

So I got to thinking... What this guy needs is a *Posse* - fearless men of good character, armed to the teeth and ready to ride, side by side, dispatching vigilante justice.

After all, it's not like he's the only one on this site who can vote to close. Granted, questions closed (or re-opened...) without moderator assistance are rare as hen's teeth in these parts, but in theory it *could* happen...

So if there be among you users who feel, like Aaronaught, that questions in this tag could use some fixin', I challenge you to step up and nominate yourselves for this thankless task.

Here are the criteria:

- Have close votes. Will use them.

If you're *ready and willing*, post below. Once there are enough of you to form a posse, *you ride*...

Comment: This post was approved by Aaron*t and also Gordon's Gin (I'm assuming).

Comment: Jackalope Gin, actually... I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: So if I get this straight, there's a posse armed with hen's teeth which will be exorcising unicorns from the stables while eating s'mores?

Comment: I joined, but I'm running out of votes!

Comment: I'll be periodically checking the closed vote list to help along with any clear-cut cases that have amassed at least a couple of close votes.

Comment: @ammoQ: I know, exhausting isn't it?  I'm out of votes for the second day in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I'll help. It would be good to have some sort of mechanism so that we don't overlap too much. For example, each question in the targeted tag will only have the outcome of close or leave. It would be time-wasting and inefficient for us not to know questions already deemed as satisfactory.

Comment: At the current ratio of good questions to bad in that tag, it's a pretty safe bet that at least 1 out of every 2 questions you check will already have one or more close votes!

Answer (score 1):

I just got my shiny new Deputy badge so I feel compelled to join the posse - I'm going thru some of the open ones and flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: Getting some invalids on things that seem overly language specfic or language comparison, feedback please?  I don't want to waste anyone's time.

Comment: No time's wasted. :) Language-specific questions are generally okay. The Ruby vs C# question was answerable and got a good answer, so I think that's why your flag got dismissed. The Google Go question did not belong on SO. Don't sweat the valid/invalid stuff too much. Nobody can be 100% right and it's possible that the moderator reviewing your flags will make a mistake, too. Keep flagging. We appreciate the help and we examine every flag. Thanks!

Comment: I just handled a bunch of your latest flags and they all looked pretty good to me. Keep up the good work: it does help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been helping out and thought I'd post so people know. When I'm on the site I always watch the new questions, and as I become aware of tags that need cleaning I'll be going through them as well.