# 7 years old closed as off-topic question (4 years ago) being edited

Tags: support, editing

I know that sometimes [tags are being removed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/why-are-old-questions-edited) and old questions are edited.

Today [a 7 years old question closed 4 years ago as `off-topic`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153372/function-works-fine-without-return-value-in-c) received [two](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/153372/4) (103 rep) [updates](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/153372/5) (3917 rep) that only fixes grammar and formatting.

Why are this edits approved or allowed? The question is still `off-topic` and this pollutes the Home > Active page

**EDIT (PLOT TWIST):** The question was -2 yesterday and today is +2 (gained 4 upvotes just with formatting and grammar edits...)

Comment: The first update might have been from someone having found the question via a search, and making improvements.  The second is likely from the review queue.  Since the first editor has a low reputation, the proposed edit needs to pass a review, and a reviewer can make revisions to the edit.  As both actions would cause the question to appear on the recent activity page, it has been exposed to numerous people that have not seen the question before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure about the specific question you're asking about, but a quite likely reason you'll see more of this type of activity occurring (i.e., old posts being edited) now is as explained in the main meta question [Retire Werewolf Hunter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340049/retire-werewolf-hunter). In particular, it's due to the "winter bash" starting, with:

> The culprit, of course, is the Werewolf Hunter hat (*given out for editing 5 questions on meta that were posted more than a year ago*), which encourages people to edit old posts.

Note a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340049/retire-werewolf-hunter#comment1136291_340049) there says:

> Ah. This explains why a bunch of old Physics.SE posts got trivial edits yesterday.

Comment: Hi John, but this question is not a meta question, is on the main site :/

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete It could be just a coincidence, but note that not everybody reads carefully, so some people might consider this hat to also apply to the main site.

Comment: @JohnOmielan or they're hoping for a secret hat.

Comment: @candied_orange Note the so-called "secret" hats for this year are shown, along with hidden text describing them, in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339894/562482) to [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f).

Comment: @JohnOmielan, that list only shows the secret hats that have already been awarded. As long as nobody has hit the trigger for a secret hat, nobody (except certain SE employees) knows about its existence.